# How to get String key from HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap, getvalue

I have a HashMap with String key and String value. I want to get an item from list, I tried to give key and wanted to get value but it gives an error. 
The following example how can I get "both" value with give the key "blazer"?

```
 HashMap<String,String> upper = new HashMap<>();
 upper.put("shoulder","both");
 upper.put("blazer","both");

 if(upper.get(upper.get("blazer"))) {} //gives an "incompatible types" error. 
 //Error: Required: boolean Found: java.lang.String
```

Comment: [The code shown compiles fine](https://ideone.com/JqWD6w).

Comment: You'll get null in this case since upper.get(upper.get("blazer")); is the same as upper.get("both"); and since you don't have an entry with a key value of both you'll get null. It's not clear what you were going for.

Comment: @Barns so sorry, I edited my question and solve it.

Comment: That is better. Now, (even though you did not post the stack trace) we can understand why you are getting the error. Removing downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Understand that `upper.get(key)` will not return a `boolean` value. You have defined your `HashMap` as follows:

```
HashMap<String,String> upper = new HashMap<>();
```

This means that both the `key` and `value` will be of type `String`. Thus, providing a valid `key` the the `get()` method will return a `String`:

```
String myValue = upper.get("blazer");
```

If you wish to check if a `key` is available before you attempt to read the value you can use the method `containsKey()` with will return a `boolean` value indicating whether the `HashMap` contains an entry with the given `key`:

```
if(upper.containsKey("blazer")){
    String myValue = upper.get("blazer");
    Log.e(TAG, "Yes blazer is available : " + myValue);
} 
else{
    Log.e(TAG, "No blazer is available!");
}
```

You can also iterate through the available `key`s like this:

```
Set<String> set = map.keySet();
for(String s : set){
    Log.e(TAG, "Map key = " + s + " value = " + map.get(s));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

They way you have it there `upper.get(upper.get("blazer"));` would just return null.

You're passing in `upper.get("blazer")` (which would return "both") to your outer `upper.get`. Since you have no "both" key stored in your map, it returns null.

Should be:

```
upper.get("blazer");
```

Comment: Why should it be that? It's unclear what OP is trying to do.

Comment: To get a value from a hashmap, you need to give it the key `map.get(key)`. In this case the key is `"blazer"`

Comment: OP is already giving a key of the correct type, for both calls to `upper.get`.

Comment: True, what OP is doing is the same as `upper.get("both");` and since there is no key `"both"` it doesn't work. Not sure what's up with the `incompatible types` error though, maybe we're missing something

Comment: @Sacha sorry, that's my fault. I copied and pasted code block, that line was in the if case. if(upper.get(upper.get("blazer"))) so it gave me incompatible types error. I realized my fault when you answered the question.